# Re-merging after "Selective" or "Partial" Merge

Tags: git, merge

Here's a reproducible example of the problem I've gotten myself into:

**Setup**

```
mkdir test-git
cd test-git
git init
echo 'Hello, world.' > file1.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'init commit'
git branch branch2
git checkout branch2
echo 'Hello, universe' > file1.txt
echo 'Foobar' > file2.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'commit 2'
```

I wanted to merge branch2 into master but only the changes to `file1.txt`, so here's what I did:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch2 --no-commit --no-ff
git reset -- file2.txt
git commit -m 'Partially Merged Branch2 into Master!'
```

So here's where I realized that might not have been a good idea... Let's say I changed my mind and I now want to merge file2.txt in as well.  I can run:

```
git merge branch2
```

> Response: Already up-to-date.

If I run `git diff branch2 --name-status` it returns `D file2.txt`, so I guess when I unstaged file2.txt it tracked this as a deletion?  I still don'y completely understand why I can't merge over and it wouldn't add the file (I obviously don't understand git's merge algorithm very well).

Unfortunately, my currently scenario is much more complicated than this so I can't exactly reverse the commit.  Is there an easy way to remerge the differences between `master` and `branch2`, without rewriting history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git a merge commit is supposed to have all necessary changes from all its parents. So if a committer deliberately decided to pick a certain version of a file like you did, then the resulting commit is considered as "a right merge" and it's impossible to perform "further merge".

This behavior has its reasons. Suppose one makes an additional change to `file2.txt` in `branch2` after the 1st merge commit, and then perform another merge of `branch2` into `master` (a quite typical situation, isn't it?). What should be considered as a correct state of `file2.txt`. I would expect that the second merge should contain only changes made between two merges, right? But you desire some other behavior, when git collects all the changes to `file2.txt` unapplied so far since the beginning of history. That would be quite annoying.

Nevertheless you can do an "alternative merge". That is, jump to a commit before the merge on `master` branch (in your example, 'init commit') and then issue `git merge` once again.

If history rewriting isn't appropriate for your needs, you might create a new branch `b3` at that commit, perform the merge, and then merge `b3` back to master. Definitely, you will receive a merge conflict on `file2.txt` and should resolve it by providing a "proper variant" for it.

Comment: Ya that totally makes sense.  Despite using git for years, I'm starting to realize that I really don't have as solid understanding as I though I did.  Wouldn't reseting master to the init commit and then remerging cause history to be rewritten?

Comment: Indeed it will. Updated the answer.