# SmartGit: Merge items I excluded/discarded on previous merge

Tags: git, merge, smartgit

Say I have my branch `Alabama`, that contains a set of changes (in files `foo` , `bar` and `hello`) compared to the `develop` which it is based on and I have a (fresh) branch `Boston` that is also based on `develop` which has no changes compared to develop yet.

`Boston` is my current local branch and I merged `Alabama` into my working tree, but discarded the changes to `foo`. I pushed, no conflicts, did a few other commits, everything is fine. Now I decide I need those changes to `foo`: I try to merge `Alabama` into my working tree again, but the changes to `foo` don't get merged since SmartGit seems to sort of remember that I decided to not use these changes and now automatically discards them for me.

What's the right way to get the changes to `foo` into `Alabama`? ;-)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727996/re-merging-after-selective-or-partial-merge/36728406#36728406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy to clean up your problem is to *rebase* the `Boston` branch on `Alabama`.  Consider the following diagram:

```
Alabama: d <- A1 <- A2
Boston:  d <- M1 <- B1 <- B2
```

Here the `d` commit is one commit (possibly of many) in the `develop` branch.  You can see that both `Alabama` and `Boston` sit on top of this common history.  The `A` commits correspond to the `Alabama` branch, and one or more of them contains the changes for the file `foo` which you want to bring into the `Boston` branch.  The `B` commits correspond to the `Boston` branch.  The commit `M1` is the merge commit resulting from your attempt to merge `Alabama` into `Boston` while discarding the change for the file `foo`.

If you *rebase* the `Boston` branch on `Alabama`, the diagram will look like this afterwards:

```
Alabama: d <- A1 <- A2
Boston:  d <- A1 <- A2 <- M1' <- B1' <- B2'
```

Here are the commands to do this:

```
git checkout Boston
git rebase Alabama
```

In other words, the work you did in the `Boston` branch will now be sitting on top of `Alabama`, which will include the changes to the file `foo`.  The prime markings on some of the commits (e.g. `B1'`) indicate that these are actually *new* commits in the `Boston` branch.  Also, you may get merge conflicts during the rebase.  In particular, expect conflicts when you replay the `M1` commit on top of `Alabama`, since there will be very similar changes from both commits.